# Function of "unattended" in "Luggage left unattended will be taken away by the police"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, passive-voice, participial-phrases

In the following sentence, does "unattended" function as a subject complement of "luggage"?

**Luggage left unattended will be taken away by the police**

P.S: I am well aware that the constituent [left unattended] is a participle clause that functions as a modifier of "Luggage", I am reluctant, however, to call "unattended" a **subject complement** simply because that would mean "left" is of *linking verb pattern*, when in fact, it is of *complex transitive pattern* ? I am wondering if it could be a *verb complement* (of "left") could you please enlighten me ?

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary says [unattended](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unattended) is an adjective.

Comment: I understand that it is an AP, but what is its function?

Comment: Again I am not talking about the meaning of"unattended" but its syntactic function

Comment: basically a duplicate - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76737/is-leave-a-linking-verb

Comment: Good of you to mention *complex transitive pattern*, although I don't know that everyone here will be familiar with it (it's the one from *Who made you boss?*). Some might know it, misleadingly, as a "double accusative", but that fails with resultative adjectives. Maybe folks would find these types of relationships you're asking about here more easily understood  if they were written more  along the lines of “You should not **leave luggage *unattended***. If you do, we will **hold you *responsible"***.  Notice now how both *unattended* and *responsible* have the same syntactic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoGEL discusses "variants of complex transitive complementation", including the type "[C7] Object + *-ed* participle complementation" (section 16.54). It mentions three main groups of verbs and then "a fourth group . . . peripheral to this construction":

> (iv) Verbs for which the *-ed* participle describes a resulting state: *find*, *discover*, *leave*
> They *found* / *discovered* / *left* him worn out by travel and exertion.

By analogy, we could turn the first part of your sentence into:

> People left luggage unattended.

However, in your sentence "left" is a past participle modifying "luggage". CoGEL claims that "there is no passive for most verbs in pattern [C7], and at best the passive is dubious." However, it notes an exception for the fourth group:

> The acceptability of the passive with Type (iv) is exceptional: *The car was found abandoned*. This is, indeed, an indication that Type (iv) may not belong here so much as with the object complement construction [C1], the participle construction being adjectival (*cf*: *an abandoned car*).

Therefore, CoGEL provides support for calling this either "complex transitive complementation" or "object complementation".<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Your sentence makes "luggage" a subject rather than object, so perhaps "subject complementation" would be a better term.

Answer (score -1):

### It's an [object complement](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm)

It states what the luggage has become - it was attended luggage, and now it is unattended luggage.

I suspect that the reason the notice is phrased as "luggage left unattended" rather than the more concise, equally intelligible, and almost identical in meaning "unattended luggage" is because:

1. It is trying to introduce the transitive notion to distinguish between momentarily unattended luggage and luggage that has been left unattended for a longer period. That is, it takes luggage some time to go from being attended to being unattended once the attendant has ceased attending it; and
2. It was drafted by a lawyer - probably before 1980.

Point 2. is probably why we have "taken away" rather than "removed" as well.